# Merging dataframes together in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dictionary of pandas dataframes, each frame contains timestamps and market caps corresponding to the timestamps, the keys of which are:

```
coins = ['dashcoin','litecoin','dogecoin','nxt']
```

I would like to create a new key in the dictionary 'merge' and using the pd.merge method merge the 4 existing dataframes according to their timestamp (I want completed rows so using 'inner' join method will be appropriate.

Sample of one of the data frames:

```
data2['nxt'].head()
Out[214]:
timestamp   nxt_cap
0   2013-12-04  15091900
1   2013-12-05  14936300
2   2013-12-06  11237100
3   2013-12-07  7031430
4   2013-12-08  6292640
```

I'm currently getting a result using this code:

```
data2['merged'] = data2['dogecoin']

for coin in coins:
    data2['merged'] = pd.merge(left=data2['merged'],right=data2[coin], left_on='timestamp', right_on='timestamp')
```

but this repeats 'dogecoin' in 'merged', however if `data2['merged']` is not `= data2['dogecoin']` (or some similar data) then the merge function won't work as the values are non existent in 'merge'

EDIT: my desired result is create one merged dataframe seen in a new element in dictionary 'data2' (data2['merged']), containing the merged data frames from the other elements in data2

Comment: What is your desired end result? A dictionary of dataframes or one merged dataframe? Or a new dataframe element in existing dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the generalized `pd.merge()` with actual named df but you must begin dataframe with at least a first one:

```
data2['merged'] = data2['dashcoin']

# LEAVE OUT FIRST ELEMENT
for coin in coins[1:]: 
      data2['merged'] = data2['merged'].merge(data2[coin], on='timestamp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already made `coins` a list, why not just something like

```
data2['merged'] = data2[coins[0]]
for coin in coins[1:]:
    data2['merged'] = pd.merge(....
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this question isn't specific to dataframes, it's just about how to write a loop when the first element has to be treated differently to the rest.